# Why does IQueryable.All() return true on an empty collection?

Tags: .net, linq, logic

So I ran into a situation today where some production code was failing precisely because a method performed exactly as [documented in MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534754.aspx).  Shame on me for not reading the documentation.  However, I'm still scratching my head as to *why* it behaves this way, even if "by design", since this behavior is exactly opposite what I would have expected (and other, known behaviors) and therefore seems to violate the principle of least surprise.

The `All()` method allows you to supply a predicate (such as a lambda expression) to test an `IQueryable`, returning a Boolean value that indicates whether all collection members match the test.  So far so good.  Here's where it gets weird.  `All()` also returns `true` if the collection is empty.  This seems completely backwards to me, for the following reasons:

- If the collection is empty, a test like this is, at best, undefined.  If my driveway is empty, I cannot assert that all cars parked there are red.  With this behavior, on an empty driveway all cars parked there are red AND blue AND checkerboard - all of these expressions would return true.
- For anyone familiar with the SQL notion that NULL != NULL, this is unexpected behavior.
- The `Any()` method behaves as expected, and (correctly) returns false because it does not have any members that match the predicate.

So my question is, why does `All()` behave this way?  What problem does it solve?  Does this violate the principle of least surprise?

I tagged this question as .NET 3.5, though the behavior also applies to .NET 4.0 as well.

**EDIT**  Ok, so I grasp the logic aspect to this, as so excellently laid out by Jason and the rest of you.  Admittedly, an empty collection is something of an edge case.  I guess my question is rooted in the struggle that, just because something is *logical* doesn't mean it necessarily makes *sense* if you're not in the correct frame of mind.

Comment: False means the query didn't return any results even without the predicate. Which is just an incomplete way of stating what Dested posted as I was typing this.

Comment: I'm removing the [`subjective`] tag from your post; this is not a subjective issue. These are the rules of logic and they are quite logical. They become intuitive once you have enough practice with the ideas.

Comment: "They become intuitive..."  Yes, I studied logic tables, etc. in university...  15 years ago.  :)

Comment: My thought is the difference of opinion on whether it makes "practical" sense is a matter if what you're practicing. If you're concerned with "all" meaning "there is no instance to the contrary", the hard logical definition is perfectly suitable for you. But for many problems we may be looking for "there is no instance to the contrary, and at least one instance of my desired scenario". It's really two claims so it would be two distinct conditions in Linq. Count(condition) > 0 and All(condition). I am indeed curious if there is a clever way to make it one.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

> If my driveway is empty, I cannot assert that all cars parked there are red.

Consider the following statements.

> `S1`: My driveway is empty.
>
> `S2`: All the cars parked in my driveway are red.

I claim that `S1` implies `S2`. That is, the statement `S1 => S2` is true. I will do this by showing that its negation is false. In this case, the negation of `S1 => S2` is `S1 ^ ~S2`; this is because `S1 => S2` is false only when `S1` is true and `S2` is false. What is the negation of `S2`? It is

> `~S2`: There exists a car parked in my driveway that is not red.

What is the truth value of `S1 ^ ~S2`? Let's write it out

> `S1 ^ ~S2`: My driveway is empty and there exists a car parked in my driveway that is not red.

The only way that `S1 ^ ~S2` can be true is if both `S1` and `~S2` are true. But `S1` says that my driveway is empty and `S2` says that there exists a car in my driveway. My driveway can not be both empty and contain a car. Thus, it is impossible for `S1` and `~S2` to both be true. Therefore, `S1 ^ ~S2` is false so its negation `S1 => S2` is true.

Therefore, if your driveway is empty you can assert that all cars parked there are red.

So now let's consider an `IEnumerable<T> elements` and a `Predicate<T> p`. Let us suppose that `elements` is empty. We wish to discover the value of

```
bool b = elements.All(x => p(x));
```

Let's consider its negation

```
bool notb = elements.Any(x => !p(x));
```

For `notb` to be true, there must be at least one `x` in `elements` for which `!p(x)` is true. But `elements` is empty so it is impossible to find an `x` for which `!p(x)` is true. Therefore `notb` can not be true so it must be false. Since `notb` is false, its negation is true. Therefore `b` is true and `elements.All(x => p(x))` must be true if `elements` is empty.

Here's one more way to think of this. The predicate `p` is true if for *all* `x` in `elements` you can not find *any* for which it is false. But if there are no items in `elements` then it is impossible to find *any* for which it is false. Thus, for an empty collection `elements`, `p` is true for *all* `x` in `elements`

Now, what about `elements.Any(x => p(x))` when `elements` is an empty `IEnumerable<T>` and `p` is a `Predicate<T>` as above? We already know the result will be false because we know its negation is true, but let's reason through it anyway; the intuition is valuable. For `elements.Any(x => p(x))` to be true there must be at least one `x` in `elements` for which `p(x)` is true. But if there aren't *any* `x` in `elements` it is impossible to find *any* `x` for which `p(x)` is true. Therefore, `elements.Any(x => p(x))` is false if `elements` is empty.

Finally, here's a [related explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/145509/why-does-abcd-startswith-return-true/390801#390801) on why `s.StartsWith(String.Empty)` is true when `s` is a non-null instance of `string`:

Comment: Computer science and logic DEPEND on semantics, and in fact make all the difference in meaning.

Comment: The problem is a false statement is not the truth just because you can't prove it wrong. Exhibit 1: [Flying Spaghetti Monster](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flying_Spaghetti_Monster). It is at most indeterminate. Saying "all cars in my driveway are red" is semantically incorrect because it implies there is at least one red car in your driveway. So the implemented behavior does fit the meaning of the word "All". The whole purpose of using words to name a method is to give it meaning to its reader. This method's name is specious and would be better off named `Method1`.

Comment: If all my children have red hair then I get a raise. I have no children. Cool, I get a raise :-D

Comment: I understand why they did it from a logical perspective, but it can have rather unintuitive side-effects.

Comment: All should throw an exception if the IEnumerable is empty, or it should be called 'AllOrEmpty', or return false when empty and be called 'AllAndNotEmpty'

Comment: There are posts here to explain it with mathematics. There is this lngthy explanation to show why any predicate does match "nothing". It makes no sense. How can all of my "nothing" in fact be red cars? How can all my "nothing" not be spaceships? All this just highlights the problem that `All` is a bad name for the method.

Answer (score 11):

If the number of the items that return `true` is the same as the number of all the items, then return `true`. Simple as that:

```
Driveway.Cars(a => a.Red).Count() == Driveway.Cars.Count()
```

Related explanation: [Why does "abcd".StartsWith("") return true?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/145509/why-does-abcd-startswith-return-true)

Answer (score 6):

`Any()` and `All()` are just implementations of the usual mathematical operators ∃ (the "existential quatifier" or "there exists") and ∀ (the "universal quatifier" or "for all").

"Any" means that there exists some item for which the predicate is true. For the empty collection, this would be false.

"All" means that there does not exist any item for which the predicate is false. For the empty collection, this would always be true.

Answer (score 5):

> "If the collection is empty, a test
>   like this is, at best, undefined. If
>   my driveway is empty, I cannot assert
>   that all cars parked there are red."

Yes you can.

To prove me wrong, show me a car on your empty driveway that is not red.

> For anyone familiar with the SQL notion that NULL != NULL, this is unexpected behavior.

This is a quirk of SQL (and not quite true: `NULL = NULL` and `NULL <> NULL` are both undefined, and neither will match any rows.)

Comment: So show me a car on my empty driveway that is not red, that is red.

Comment: Both statements are true.  (1) There is no car on your driveway that is red and (2) There is no car on your driveway that is **not** red.  No contradiction there.

Comment: I think that was what I was getting at - divorced from the whole All => !(!Any) question, the test can be both true and false from the perspective that there is not an element that does *not* match, but there is not an element that *does* match, either.

Answer (score 4):

`All(x => x.Predicate)` is the opposite of `Any(x => !x.Predicate)` ("Are all cars red?" is the opposite of "Are there any cars that aren't red?").

`Any(x => !x.Predicate)` returns `false` for empty collections (which appears natural for the common understanding of "any").

Hence `All(x => x.Predicate)` should (and does) return `true` for empty collections.

Answer (score 3):

I think it makes sense. In logic, the complement of FOR ALL is NOT (THERE EXIST). FOR ALL is like `All()`. THERE EXIST is like `Any()`.

So `IQueryable.All()` is equivalent to `!IQueryable.Any()`. If your `IQueryable` is empty, then both returns true based on MSDN doc.

Comment: IQueryable.All() is NOT equivalent to !IQueryable.Any(). You need to negate the predicate as well.

Answer (score 3):

Because any proposition to an empty set would be a [vacuous truth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuous_truth).

Answer (score 3):

Now that everything has been said, don't break the semantics and create a new extension method:

```
  public static Boolean AllOrFalseIfEmpty<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Func<T, Boolean> predicate) {
     return source.Any() && source.All(predicate);
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

You will find this behaviour quite often in other areas of mathematics or computer science.

The SUM operator in Math will return 0 (the neutral element of +) in cases where the ranges are invalid (the SUM from 0 up to -1). The MULTIPYL operator will return 1 (neutral element for multiplication).

Now if you have Boolean expressions, it's quite similar: The neutral element for OR is `false` (`a OR false = a`) whereas the neutral element for AND is `true`.

Now on Linq's `ANY` and `ALL`: They are similar to this:

```
ANY = a OR b OR c OR d ...
ALL = a AND b AND c AND d ...
```

So this behavior is just what "you would expect" if you have a math/cs background.

Answer (score 1):

Returning `true` is also logical. You have two statements: **"Have a car?"** and **"Is it red?"** If the first statement is `false`, it doesn't matter what the second statement is, the result is `true` by [modus ponens](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modus_ponens).

Answer (score 0):

It's very similar to the basic concept of the number zero.  Even though it represents the existence of absence, it still possesses and represents a value.  IQueryable.All() should return true, because it will successfully return all of the members of the collection.  It just so happens that if the collection is empty, the function won't return any members, but not because the function *couldn't* return any members.  It was only because there were no members to return.  That being said, why should IQueryable.All() have to experience failure due to the lack of support from the collection?  It was willing, it was able...it was capable.  Sounds to me like the collection couldn't hold up their end of the bargain...

[Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20171221161514/http://mathforum.org/dr.math/faq/faq.divideby0.html)