# Why does [].all?{|a| a.include?('_')} return true?

Tags: ruby, logic, boolean-logic

Why does

```
[].all?{|a| a.include?('_')}
```

return `true`?

Comment: Isomorphic to [Why does IQueryable.All() return true on an empty collection?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2195289/why-does-iqueryable-all-return-true-on-an-empty-collection)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your code asks about the truth of the following statement: "For all elements `a` in the empty list, `a` includes the character `'_'`." Because there are no elements in the empty list, the statement is true. (This is referred to as [vacuous truth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuous_truth) in logic.) It might be easier to understand if you instead try to find a way to make that expression false. This would require having *at least one element* in the empty list which *did not* contain `'_'`. However, the empty list is empty, so no such element can exist. Therefore, the statement can't meaningfully be false, so it must be true.

Comment: The only answerer, who doesn't play role of Captain Obvious.

Answer (score 7):

`all?` will pass every element of the array to the block `{|a| a.include?('_')}`, and return `true` if the block doesn't return `false` or `nil` for any of the elements. Since the array has no elements, the block will never return `false` or `nil` and so `all?` returns `true`.

Answer (score 2):

`all?` returns true if the block never returns false or nil. The block never gets called, therefore it never returns false or nil and therefore `all?` returns true.

Answer (score 1):

Even

```
[].all?{ false }
```

returns `true`, for the reasons explained in bcat's answer.