# Why do any and all on an empty list return different things?

Tags: python

In chapter 2 of *[Data Science from Scratch](https://smile.amazon.com/Data-Science-Scratch-Principles-Python/dp/149190142X?sa-no-redirect=1)* by Joel Grus, the following examples are provided:

```
all([ ]) # True, no falsy elements in the list

any([ ]) # False, no truthy elements in the list
```

According to Grus, Python treats `[]` (an empty list) as a "falsey" argument. So why do we get different results based on whether the `all()` or `any()` argument is applied to an empty list?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Per [the documentation of `all`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all):

> **`all(iterable)`**
>
> Return `True` if all elements of the iterable are true **(or if the iterable is empty)**.

And the [documentation for `any`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any):

> **`any(iterable)`**
>
> Return `True` if any element of the iterable is true. **If the iterable is empty, return `False`.**

An empty iterable `[]` is falsey, but it doesn't matter as the return value is just by implementation.

---

If you're wondering *why* this happens, it's just a consequence of the implementation. If you look at the equivalent code for `all` from the documentation:

> ```
> def all(iterable):
>     for element in iterable:
>         if not element:
>             return False
>     return True
> ```

Because of this specific implementation, if the iterable is empty, the `for` loop is skipped completely as there are no elements. Thus, it returns `True`. For `any`, the documentation provides the equivalent code:

> ```
> def any(iterable):
>     for element in iterable:
>         if element:
>             return True
>     return False
> ```

The reason it returns `False` for an empty iterable is the same reason `all` return `True`. Since there are no elements in the list, the `for` loop is skipped and it returns `False`.

This implementation does have a reasoning, since empty set logic makes `all` return true, see [this Math.SE post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/202452/why-is-predicate-all-as-in-allset-true-if-the-set-is-empty) and [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2195289/why-does-iqueryable-all-return-true-on-an-empty-collection). `all` can be thought of as "there are as many true elements as elements". Since an empty set has no true elements and no elements, it returns true because 0 equals 0. `any` can be thought of as "there's at least one...", and since the set is empty, there's not at least one because there is not even one element. Thus `all` returns true for an empty set, and `any` returns false for an empty set.

Answer (score 4):

The logical reasoning behind this definition is as follows:

`any` is related to the **existential quantifier** while `all` is related to the **universal quantifier** and follows their logical norms.

Translate `any` as **there is at least one**: At least one element of `[]` evaluates to true <-- NO.

See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/281735/quantification-over-the-empty-set or https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/202452/why-is-predicate-all-as-in-allset-true-if-the-set-is-empty -