# IndexOf method returns 0 when it should had return -1 in C# / Java

Tags: c#, java, string, logic, indexof

A friend of mine came to me with this strange behavior which i can't explain, any insight view would be appreciated.

Im running VS 2005 (C# 2.0), the following code show the behavior

```
int rr = "test".IndexOf("");
Console.WriteLine(rr.ToString());
```

the above code, print "0" which clearly show it should have return -1

This also happen in Java where the following Class show the behavior:

```
public class Test{
 public static void main(String[] args){
   System.out.println("Result->"+("test".indexOf("")));
 }
}
```

Im running Java 1.6.0_17

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3872936/why-do-strings-start-with-a-in-java and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/145509/why-does-abcd-startswith-return-true

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is not an exception to the rule, but rather a natural consequence of how `indexOf` and `startsWith` are defined.

You’re claiming that `"test".indexOf("")` should return `-1`. This is essentially equivalent to the claim that `"test".startsWith("")` should return `false`. Why is this? Although this case is specifically addressed in the documentation as returning `true`, this is not just an arbitrary decision.

How would you decide `"test".startsWith("te")`, for example? The simplest way is to use recursion. Since both strings start with the character `'t'`, you call `"est".startsWith("e")` and return the result. Similarly, you will call `"st".startsWith("")` and return the result. But you already know that the answer should be `true`, so that is why every string starts with `""`.

Answer (score 21):

Quote from the C# [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k8b1470s.aspx):

> If value is [Empty](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.empty.aspx), the return value
>   is 0.

The behavior that you describe is entirely as expected (at least in C#).

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out for C# (So it seems an Exception to the rule). On its counter part (JavaDoc), is not well explained that this behavior will be expected.

Comment: @jcgarciam: good point; I'll update the answer indicating that it is related to C#.

Answer (score 11):

0 is correct. Start at position zero and you *can* (trivially) match a zero-length string. Likewise, "" *contains* "".

Comment: that would be fine if that would have been my example, i tried:

"Test".IndexOf("");

which is different at what you explain.

Comment: @jcgarciam not really. Look at it this way; in what way does it **not** start with (or contain) "". Show me the character that isn't a match. There isn't one, therefore it is is a match.

Answer (score 6):

0 is correct.  The Javadocs point out that `indexOf` works as follows:

> The integer returned is the smallest
>   value k such that:
>
> ```
>  this.startsWith(str, k)
> ```

Any string starting with `""` is equal to the original string (and every string starts with `""`), so the smallest `k` for `str = ""` is always 0.

Comment: Sorry, but i can't understand your reasoning on this.

Comment: *Every single string* starts with ""

Likewise, every single set is a superset of an empty set.

Etc...

It is a very convenient convention.

Answer (score 3):

Think of it this way: IndexOf, when looking for a string, will start at position 0, try to match the string, if it doesn't fit, move on to position 1, 2, etc. When you call it with an empty string, it attempts to match the empty string with the string starting at position 0 with length 0. And hooray, nothing equals nothing.

Side note: There's no real reason to use `ToString` when you're using Console.Write/WriteLine. The function automatically calls the `ToString` method of the object in question. (Unless overloading ToString)

Comment: At index position 0, "test" does not hold "nothing" it has a "t". Voted +1 for the way you put it.:)

Comment: as ring said, at position 0 it doesn't hold "nothing". But thanks anyway!

It seems this is explained in the Documentation. I will put this as an Exception to the rule of how IndexOf is suppose to works.

Answer (score 2):

It should return 0. You are looking for the first occurrence of an empty string, right? :)

Answer (score 1):

Just for the fun of it. It also works like that in python

```
>>> "test".startswith("")
True
>>> "test".index("")
0
```

Python throws a ValueError instead of the -1 that is nice.

```
>>> "test".index('r')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: substring not found
```

Answer (score 1):

More fun php actually does a way better job!

```
php -r "print strpos('test','');"
PHP Warning:  strpos(): Empty delimiter. in Command line code on line 1
```