# Java StringTokenizer, empty null tokens

Tags: java, string, stringtokenizer, split

I am trying to split a string into 29 tokens..... stringtokenizer won't return null tokens. I tried string.split, but I believe I am doing something wrong:

```
String [] strings = line.split(",", 29);
```

sample inputs:

```
10150,15:58,23:58,16:00,00:00,15:55,23:55,15:58,00:01,16:03,23:58,,,,,16:00,23:22,15:54,00:03,15:59,23:56,16:05,23:59,15:55,00:01,,,,
10155,,,,,,,,,,,07:30,13:27,07:25,13:45,,,,,,,,,,,07:13,14:37,08:01,15:23
10160,10:00,16:02,09:55,16:03,10:06,15:58,09:48,16:07,09:55,16:00,,,,,09:49,15:38,10:02,16:04,10:00,16:00,09:58,16:01,09:57,15:58,,,,
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you want the trailing empty strings to be kept, but you don't want to give a magic number for maximum, use a negative limit:

```
line.split(",", -1)
```

If `line.equals("a,,c")`, then `line.split(",", -1)[1].isEmpty()`; it's not `null`. This is because when `","` is the delimiter, then `",,"` has an empty string between the two delimiters, not `null`.

---

**Example:**

Using the explanation above, consider the following example: `",,"`

Although you might expect `","`,  `null`, and `","`.

The actual result is `","`,  `""` and `","`

---

If you want `null` instead of empty strings in the array returned by `split`, then you'd have to manually scan the array and replace them with `null`. I'm not sure why `s == null` is better than `s.isEmpty()`, though.

#### See also

- [Java `String.indexOf` and empty strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2683466/java-string-indexof-and-empty-strings)

Comment: I was checking things wrong. 29 actually works. -1 does too.
Thansk

Comment: yeah I noticed that. I just check if the string is empty rather than null.

Comment: @user69: use `isEmpty()` if Java6, use `length() == 0` otherwise. Don't use `equals("")`.

Answer (score 5):

Use `StringUtils.splitPreserveAllTokens()` in [Apache Commons Lang](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/) library

Answer (score 2):

If you want *empty tokens* to be retained `string.split` won't work satisfactorily. `StringTokenizer` will also no work.
I have come with following method, which might be helpful for you

```
public static String[] splitTotokens(String line, String delim){
  String s = line;
  int i = 0;

  while (s.contains(delim)) {
  s = s.substring(s.indexOf(delim) + delim.length());
      i++;
  }
  String token = null;
  String remainder = null;
  String[] tokens = new String[i];

  for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
    token = line.substring(0, line.indexOf(delim));
    //System.out.print("#" + token + "#");
    tokens[j] = token;
    remainder = line.substring(line.indexOf(delim) + delim.length());
    //System.out.println("#" + remainder + "#");
    line = remainder;
    }

  return tokens;`  
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
use this org.springframework.util.StringUtils

org.springframework.util.StringUtils.delimitedListToStringArray(data, delimit);
```

This class delivers some simple functionality provides easy-to-use methods to convert between delimited strings, such as CSV strings, and collections and arrays.

Answer (score 0):

If you want empty tokens to be retained `string.split()` won't work satisfactorily. `StringTokenizer` will also not work. I have come with following method, which might be helpful for you:

```
public static String[] splitTotokens(String line, String delim){
    String s = line;
    int i = 0;

    while (s.contains(delim)) {
        s = s.substring(s.indexOf(delim) + delim.length());
        i++;
    }
    String token = null;
    String remainder = null;
    String[] tokens = new String[i];

    for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
        token = line.substring(0, line.indexOf(delim));
        // System.out.print("#" + token + "#");
        tokens[j] = token;
        remainder = line.substring(line.indexOf(delim) + delim.length());
        //System.out.println("#" + remainder + "#");

        line = remainder;
    }
    return tokens;
}
```