# java split gives different array lengths

Tags: java, split

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Java StringTokenizer, empty null tokens](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2708591/java-stringtokenizer-empty-null-tokens)

Considering this java snippet:

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s1 = "1;2;3;4;5";
        String s2 = "1;2;;;";

        String[] splits1 = s1.split(";");
        String[] splits2 = s2.split(";");

        System.out.println(splits1.length);
        System.out.println(splits2.length);
    }
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
5
2
```

---

I need some alternatives to extracting arrays with same lengths.

If there are four semicolons (";") in the searched string (ex s2) then I would like to have length=5 of splited array (splits2) with null elements where appropriate (splits2[2]=null, splits2[3]=null etc).

Can you please provide solutions?

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/785586/how-can-split-a-string-which-contains-only-delimiter) should help you. Check the voted answer.

Comment: @cosmincalistru thx for helping out, I am a bit new to programming

Answer (score 1):

**1.** Use "space" between the ";" to have the arrays of same length. **You will have Empty spaces not null**

Eg:

```
   String[] s = "1;2; ; ;" ;
```

**2. Array is an object** which can be **null**, and if it contains the **reference variable** inside it, those can be **null**, **but primitive types cannot be null.**`So i am using space.`

**/////////////////////EDITED/////////////////**

**Use this below snippet, ITS WORKING....**

```
String a = "1;2;;;;";
        char[] chArr = a.toCharArray();

        String temp = new String();
        String[] finalArr = new String[a.length()];

        for (int i = 0; i < chArr.length; i++) {

            try {
                temp = chArr[i] + "";
                Integer.parseInt(temp);
                finalArr[i] = temp;

            } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {

                finalArr[i] = null;

            }

        }
        for (String s : finalArr){
            System.out.println(s);
        }
             System.out.println(finalArr.length);
```

Comment: I shouldn't modify the searched string to have spaces between semicolons

Comment: I guess @dadu 's problem is that he can't choose the input data so trying to split the data as it is should be the solution given.

Comment: @dadu...check out my edited part.... it contains the code you want..

Comment: @KumarVivekMitra : Thanks for your ideea, it's an interesting approach. It seems that a less complicated solution is using the second parameter of split. Can you edit your answer and include as an other alternative solution: String[] splits2 = s2.split(";", -1); ?