# How can index be two things at once?

Tags: javascript

Let's say I have a string: `var a = 'testString';`

Then I got the index of `t`:

```
return a.indexOf('t');
```

That would give 0.  Now I'm going to get the index of `''`:

```
return a.indexOf('');
```

That also gives 0, yet if I return `a.charAt(0)` it returns 't'.  How is it possible for `a.indexOf('')` and `a.indexOf('t')` both be 0?

Comment: what do you mean by index of `''` an empty string

Comment: @falinsky - JavaScript != Java.

Comment: @nnnnnn Lol, it doesn't matter the language, an empty string is still an empty string...

Comment: @ManofSnow - You can't assume all languages will behave the same way for `.indexOf()` or other string searching functions, so it's not really a true duplicate. Though for JS and Java I guess they do behave the same way, and I do like the [accepted answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2683509/615754) in that other question.

Comment: @nnnnnn sure, you're right

Comment: Note that in answer to "How can index be two things at once?", with your example string `a.indexOf('test')` returns the same index as `a.indexOf('testString')` and `a.indexOf('t')`... That is, `.indexOf()` is not doing the same thing as `.charAt()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because the empty string is a substring of every string. `indexOf` is specified to return the smallest index which matches the substring, so the index returned for any string will always be 0.

Comment: Of course!  And I reread it and it turns out `indexOf` gives the first occurrence (basically what you're saying).

Comment: @ManofSnow: It's the same as the empty set being a subset of every set.