# "Hello".indexOf("") returns 0

Tags: java, string, indexof

I Just tried to find out what the compiler does if I try to find the index of a null charachter in a String.I remember somehwere that a null charachter is always appended to the end of a string, so i expected the code below to give me 5.

When I type out this:

```
String s = "Hello";
System.out.println(s.indexOf(""));
```

It gives an output of 0

Help please!

Comment: `""` is not a "null character" - it's an empty String. And Java does not store strings with a "null character" at the end. It stores them as a `char` array

Comment: `""` is not null character. It's an empty string

Comment: You're thinking of C, not java - C strings are terminated by a null character

Comment: "" and null are different

Comment: There is no null character in a Java `String` unless you add one yourself. If you want to find the end of the string, just use `s.length()`. What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: Consider `System.out.println("Hello".substring(0,0));` and `System.out.println(Arrays.toString("Hello".split("")));` - The empty `String` appears before the first character, the second character, etc...

Comment: Check out the following links, maybe they'll help! 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2683466/java-string-indexof-and-empty-strings
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4802015/difference-between-null-and-empty-java-string

Comment: Yeah that helped!Thanks luzi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, if you were looking for a null character you would probably want to do `(char)0` because `""` is an empty string (no character).

Second, if Java uses a null character (they don't have to IIRC) then they hide it.

EDIT: Struck my third point because I'm not sure about it anymore.

SECOND EDIT: I looked it up, Java strings are not null terminated.  They rely on the length field.

Comment: Thanks man!Helped!

Comment: "`(char)0`"  or `"\0"`, if you want a `String`.

Comment: Thanks again man! Just another small Q, the substring() function when given a range,like "Something".substring(2,5), it gives "met" and not "meth", so does it append a empty string or a null or something like that in the end or something like that?

Comment: The `endIndex` argument in Java is exclusive.  So you get str[2], str[3], and str[4].

Comment: Aha thanks bout that!