# Java indexOf("") returns 0

Tags: java, indexof

Can someone help and explain whether indexOf("") returns 0 is predefined same as -1 by returning a negative result?

Thanks and Happy Easter to all!

ps. the following link was helpful, but it does not contain the exact answer to my question
["Hello".indexOf("") returns 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49408366/hello-indexof-returns-0)

```
public class ExIndexOf {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String s = "We learn Java.";

        System.out.println(s.indexOf("ava"));  // -> 10
        System.out.println(s.indexOf("java")); // -1
        System.out.println(s.indexOf(" ")); // -> 2
        System.out.println(s.indexOf("")); // -> 0
    }
}
```

Comment: no, that's not the same as -1. it means that the index of "" is 0.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2683466/java-string-indexof-and-empty-strings (it is the duplicate of your linked question). If not: why not?

Comment: thx buddys! I did try, with no satisfied explanation, hence the question here raised. again thx for the effort and kindness

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `indexOf` returns the first position (index) of its argument in the string. Strings in Java, like arrays and collections are zero-indexed, meaning that the index `0` describes the first item. Index `1` is the second item and index `n` describes the `n+1`th item. Many functions return the (invalid) index `-1` (a "magic" value) to denote "not found" or "error".

The empty string is contained in every string multiple times. The *first* position where it can be found is at position 0. Think of it as: `String s = "" + "We learn Java."` (or even more verbose: `s = "" + "W" + "" + "e" + "" + " " + "" + "l" + …`).

```
String s = "We learn Java.";

System.out.println(s.indexOf(""));  // -> 0
System.out.println(s.indexOf("W")); // 0
System.out.println(s.indexOf("e")); // -> 1
System.out.println(s.indexOf(" ")); // -> 2
System.out.println(s.indexOf("not found")); // -> -1
```

Comment: Thx knittl for your prompt reply!
I come across this question because I wrote
while (searchBegin != -1 || searchBegin != 0) {
   count++;
}
and it comes to the endless loop and still I do not know why it occurs like this.

Comment: @pojna the loop is an infinite loop because `searchBegin` is always unequal to -1 OR 0 (and you never update the loop variable).
If `searchBegin == -1` then it is `!= 0`. If `searchBegin == 0`, then it is `!= -1`. If `searchBegin = 42`, then it is `!= -1` and also `!= 0`. Your condition is _always_ true, regardless of value (a "tautology").

Comment: @pojna the condition can be transformed into the equivalent form `!(searchBegin == -1 && searchBegin == 0)` – do you see the error when written in this way? A variable can never be two distinct values at the same time.

Comment: Thx knittl for your valuable comments! Sorry for my primitive questions. Yes, you are right as I changed it to &&. As I got no result feeded back to while (searchBegin != 0), I did doubt how indexOf("") reacts internally. Now I gradually come to the clue and thanks again for your help! Nice holidays!

Comment: BTW, is it really the case s = "" + "W" + "" + "e" + "" + " " + "" + "l" + …+""? 
(Does it mean at the end of the string there's also a "" attached?)
I checked the following and found last position of "" and string length are exactly the same.
String s1 = "We learn Java.";
String s2 = "";
int lastInd = s1.lastIndexOf(s2);
System.out.println(lastInd);   // 14
System.out.println(s1.length()); // 14

Comment: @pojna since the empty string is "nothing" it "appears" everywhere in a string. In the beginning, between letters, at the end. See this answer in the linked question https://stackoverflow.com/a/2683509/112968. Compare the empty string to the value 0 when adding values. You can always add 0 and the result will not change. 3 = 3 = 0 + 3 + 0 = 0 + 1 + 0 + 1 + 0 + 1 + 0 = 2 + 0 + 0 + 0 + 1

Comment: Thank you very much! Nice holiday!