# Do C# strings end with empty string?

Tags: c#, .net, string

Just a short question out of curiosity.

```
string str = "string";
Console.WriteLine(str.EndsWith(string.Empty));                  //true
Console.WriteLine(str.LastIndexOf(string.Empty) == str.Length); //false
//of course string are indexed from 0, 
//just wrote if for fun to check whether empty string get some extra index
///somehow by a miracle:)

//finally

Console.WriteLine(str.LastIndexOf(string.Empty) 
               == str.LastIndexOf('g'));                        //true :)
```

Comment: What is your concept of `string.Empty`? What _is_ it?

Comment: Everything contains nothing. Nothing is everywhere.

Comment: My question would be why are there so many up votes for such a meaningless question? Why exactly does it matter that one knows if a C# string does or does not end in an empty string? How exactly would you use such valuable information?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

[`EndsWith`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.endswith.aspx):

> Determines whether the end of this string instance matches the specified string.

All strings will match `""` at the end... or any other part of the string. Why? Because conceptually, there are empty strings around every character.

```
"" + "abc" + "" == "abc" == "" + "a" + "" + "b" + "" + "c" + ""
```

---

Update:

About your last example - this is documented on [`LastIndexOf`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1wdsy8fy.aspx):

> If value is String.Empty, the return value is the last index position in this instance.

---

A related issue is the use of null as a string terminator - which happens in C and C++, but not C#.

From MSDN - [`String Class (System)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.aspx):

> In the .NET Framework, a String object can include embedded null characters, which count as a part of the string's length. However, in some languages such as C and C++, a null character indicates the end of a string; it is not considered a part of the string and is not counted as part of the string's length.

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
string str = "string";
Console.WriteLine(str.EndsWith(string.Empty));                  //true 
Console.WriteLine(str.LastIndexOf(string.Empty) == str.Length-1); // true
Console.ReadLine();
```

So yes as Oded said, they do always match.

Comment: ooh Good plus one for having a critical site on Q? code snippet

Comment: I don't think OP's code `str.LastIndexOf(string.Empty)==str.Length` is a mistake though, as OP thinks `string.Empty` is something after **g**

Comment: Of course, strings use 0-based indexing, I just wrote it for fun to check whether empty string get some extra index somehow by a miracle:)

Comment: Which would make the string.Length = string.Length + 1 for every string :)

Comment: @Pabuc, why? can you explain it a bit further?

Comment: Yes ofcourse I can Bolu. As Oded stated, For LastIndexOf, If the value is string.empty the return value is the last index position in this instance which is length-1

Answer (score 2):

Think about it this way: `LastIndexOf` is kind of meaningless with an empty string. You could say the empty string exists at *every* index within a string, between each character. The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1wdsy8fy.aspx) thus provides a definitive answer for what should be returned:

> If value is [String.Empty](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.empty.aspx), the return
>   value is the last index position in
>   this instance.

At least in this case it returns an *actual* index. If it returned the string's length (representing the index "after" the end, which I believe was your point) it would be returning a result for a method called `LastIndexOf` that isn't even an index.

And here's another way of looking at it: If I have this:

```
Dim index As Integer = str.LastIndexOf("")
```

...then I should be able to do this:

```
Dim substr As String = str.Substring(index, "".Length)
```

...and get `""` back. Sure enough, when `LastIndexOf` returns the *last* index in the string, it works. <strike>If it returned the string's *length*, I'd get an `ArgumentOutOfRangeException`.</strike> **Edit**: Well, looks like I was wrong there. Hopefully my first point was strong enough on its own ;)

Answer (score 0):

There's a some more information in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/145509/why-does-abcd-startswith-return-true) and its answers.

In particular, `"Indeed, the empty string logically occurs between every pair of characters."`