# Bug in C# - "FooBar".StartsWith(string.Empty) is true

Tags: c#, string

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why does “abcd”.StartsWith(“”) return true?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/145509/why-does-abcd-startswith-return-true)

Something similar to this being true caught us out:

```
"FooBar".StartsWith(string.Empty)
```

Firstly I don't think it should be true but I am also not quite sure why it is true, looking at the "Reflector'ed" code:

```
public bool StartsWith(string value, bool ignoreCase, CultureInfo culture)
{
    if (value == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("value");
    }
    if (this == value)
    {
        return true;
    }
    CultureInfo info = (culture == null) ? CultureInfo.CurrentCulture : culture;
    return info.CompareInfo.IsPrefix(this, value, ignoreCase ? CompareOptions.IgnoreCase : CompareOptions.None);
}
```

ignoreCase is false and culture is null. So why does "this == value" evaluate to true?

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/145509/why-does-abcd-startswith-return-true/145516#145516

Comment: Yes I just found that question, thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not that `this == value` returns `true`, but `CompareInfo.IsPrefix` is [documented](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/32c07e63.aspx) as returning `true` for `String.Empty`:

> Every string starts and ends with an
>   empty substring (""); therefore, if
>   prefix is an empty string, this method
>   returns true.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you think `"this == value" evaluate to true?` I believe this behavior is correct. Any string may be considered to be starting with empty string.

Answer (score 0):

Actually FooBar starts with string.Empty. Any string can be considered starting with string.Empty, as well as 0+a = a.