# initialised string seems to contain string.Empty

Tags: c#, contains, string-comparison, string

I jumped into this accidentally and have no clue as to why this is happening

```
string sample = "Hello World";
if (sample.Contains(string.Empty))
{
    Console.WriteLine("This contains an empty part ? at position " + sample.IndexOf(string.Empty));
    Console.WriteLine(sample.LastIndexOf(string.Empty));
    Console.WriteLine(sample.Length);
}
```

**Output**

`This contains an empty part ? at position 0`

`10`

`11`

I am happy with the last part, but i have no idea why this is evaluated true. Even `Indexof` and `LastIndexOf` have separate values.

Could anyone help me out on why is this so?

**EDIT**

I believe this is a bit relevant to my question and would be also helpful to those who stumble upon this question.

See this SO link: [Why does "abcd".StartsWith("") return true?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/145509/why-does-abcd-startswith-return-true)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

From msdn for [IndexOf](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k8b1470s.aspx)

> If value is String.Empty, the return value is 0.

For [LastIndexOf](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1wdsy8fy.aspx)

> If value is String.Empty, the return value is the last index position in this instance.

For [Contains](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dy85x1sa%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)

> true if the value parameter occurs within this string, or if value is the empty string ("");

Comment: @SwDevMan81: shouldn't that be 11 instead of 10 ?

Comment: @V4Vendetta - last index is 10 (0 to 10 is 11 characters)

Comment: @SwDevMan81: sorry my mistake didn't read `index`, So does it imply that for any string as given above string.Empty will always resolve to true (would be glad to know if there is an exceptional case)

Comment: @V4Vendetta - Yup, it will always return true if the input is String.Empty

Comment: @SwDevMan81: well i was looking more on `why` does it do so

Comment: @SwDevMan81: Found something similar on SO.. Jason has interesting explanation ..thanks for helping me out.

Answer (score 4):

**Question**: Does the string `"Hello World"` contain String.Empty?

**Answer**: Yes.

Every possible string contains String.Empty, so your test is correctly returning true.

If you are trying to test if your string is empty, then the following code is what you want

```
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(sample)) 
{

}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is documented in the [String.Contains Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dy85x1sa%28v=vs.95%29.aspx):

> **Return Value**
>   Type: System.Boolean
>   `true` if the value parameter occurs within this string, or if value is the empty string (""); otherwise, `false`.

And in [String.IndexOf Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k8b1470s.aspx)

> If value is String.Empty, the return value is 0.

And in [LastIndexOf Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1wdsy8fy.aspx)

> If value is String.Empty, the return value is the last index position in this instance.