# Javascript String.replace() ,ambiguous results

Tags: javascript, string, str-replace

See my code

```
<html>
<body>

<script type="text/javascript">

var str="Visit Microsoft!";

document.write( str = str.replace("",'ss'));

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

The output is

```
 ssVisit Microsoft!
```

Why is it happening.?

Comment: `replace` with a string will only replace the first occurrence of that string. You pass an empty string, which is found at the beginning of the string (`"something".indexOf("")` returns `0`).

Comment: why there is empty string at the beginning of string?

Comment: Because `"Visit Microsoft!" === "" + "Visit Microsoft!"`

Comment: Between the beginning of the string and the first character, there is *nothing*. Same goes for anything between characters. The empty string can be found between any characters (you can do the same what Alex did, e.g. `"foo" + "" + "bar" === "foobar"`).

Comment: and at the end character just try indexof("") and lastIndexof("") but what are you trying to achieve ?

Comment: To further illustrate, here's what happens, if you replace _all_ empty/zero-length strings in `str`: `str.replace(new RegExp("", "g"), "-")` → `"-V-i-s-i-t- -M-i-c-r-o-s-o-f-t-!-"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is correct because every string begins with an empty string. See below post for more info:

[Why does "abcd".StartsWith("") return true?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/145509/why-does-abcd-startswith-return-true/145516#145516)