# Java split string on empty delimiter returns empty string at the beginning?

Tags: java

I want to split a string to single characters. So I do:

```
"abcd".split("");
```

But this yields:

```
["", "a", "b", "c", "d"]
```

The first empty string is not something I'm used to when doing the same in other languages (e.g. Ruby). What is the logic behind it?

Comment: Same reason: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/145509/why-does-abcd-startswith-return-true

Comment: You can use `substring(i, i+1)` or `charAt(i)` or `toCharArray()` to access characters.

Comment: But why is the empty string added only to the beginning of the array and not everywhere? (especially at the end)

Comment: There is no empty string at the end because [_"`[String#split(String)]` works as if by invoking the two-argument split method with the given expression and a limit argument of zero. Trailing empty strings are therefore not included in the resulting array."_](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why are you using `String.split()` for this? You might be better served using `String.toCharArray()`.

I know one will return you an array of Strings while the other will give you an array of chars. Since you want each character separately, I am assuming this doesn't matter to your code.

Comment: I was more interested in the strange behavior, but you are correct; that is a better way.