# (?i) regex outcome - "Nothing" is getting replaced by Something

Tags: java, regex

I was trying case insensitive pattern matching. For the sake of learning i tried the following and finding it difficult to analyze what is happening.

```
   String x = "Hello";
   String pattern = "(?i)";
   System.out.println(x.replaceAll(pattern, "</code>"));
```

Output is

```
</code>H</code>e</code>l</code>l</code>o</code>
```

Can someone please explain this behaviour

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `(?i)` bare is equivalent to matching `case-insensitive` empty String

You need to have something after `(?i)` to apply case-insensitivity matching to..

That is why this pattern matches every empty string, `after each character`, and `also before the first character`, and replaces it with : - `</code>`

Comment: >matches every empty string, after each character...
It is printing </code> in the beginning as well. 
And where does empty string exist ?. There is nothing . And How a nothing is getting replaced by something ?

Comment: @Javanator Try using `"a".contains("");` -> It will return true. Becaues every string contains at least one empty string..

Comment: Yes agree to that but question is where are these empty strings are coming from. "Hello" has only five character. And i feel to occupy memory accordingly for five characters only. nothing else

Comment: are there any java doc or other links for these magical creatures :).
That proves your statement that a empty substring to be associated with a string.

Comment: how can a thing that holds 0 space is getting matched and is getting replaced by something

Comment: @Javanator. See this post: - http://stackoverflow.com/a/145516/1679863 A Jon-Skeet answer will clear all your doubt..

Comment: @Javanator I hope I made you clear? You can also See this answer: - http://stackoverflow.com/a/263257/1679863

Comment: Yes Rohit. Infact you did it extensively . Thanks +1 and accept too

Answer (score 1):

That pattern matches nothing, and there is one nothing to either side of each character :)

(Well, there are a lot of nothings, actually, but there can only be one match per index.)

Comment: i thought the same that it is replacing nothing as i didn't provided anything after (?i). But does Nothing Exist ? Confused to think :)