# Why does "some string".Replace("","") throw a zero length exception?

Tags: c#, .net

I thought it should return the original string, like in this case, just "some string", but instead it throws a "String cannot be of zero length". Also why a string cannot be of zero length if I can have:
        string str = "";

Comment: According to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk49wtc1(v=vs.110).aspx) it should throw a `ArgumentException`.

Comment: @tkausl Thanks for reminding, I have just edited my problem.

Comment: It’s not that strings in general can’t be of zero length, but that you can’t replace the empty string in a string with something. (The empty string can be found in a lot of places – in `"a"`, there’s one before and after the “a”, no? – and it’s just simpler to write what you mean.)

Comment: It makes no sense to try to replace the empty string by something.

Comment: @dcg I just got into a situation to write something like  "asd".Replace(str??" ",""); which if str is null then replaces nothing.

Comment: @GeorgeFeng: Just write the explicit `str == null ? …` check, then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Every string contains the empty string.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/145509/why-does-abcd-startswith-return-true) If you were to try and replace the empty string with something else, `Replace()` would never finish because it would just keep adding the replacement string to your string an infinite number of times and never finish.

If you're trying to do a search-and-replace operation with a variable search string, just check if the search string is empty and don't perform the search if it is.