# startsWith string method with empty searchString

Tags: javascript, string-function

Why does startsWith method return true when the searchString is empty. I think same in other string methods like includes, endsWith. What can I do if I want to avoid it i.e. it should return false in case of empty searchString.

```
var haystack = 'Hello World!', needle ='';
console.log( haystack.startsWith( needle ) );
```

Comment: possible to duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/145509/why-does-abcd-startswith-return-true

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does "abcd".StartsWith("") return true?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/145509/why-does-abcd-startswith-return-true)

Answer (score 4):

Because it is designed to return so. Empty strings denote the existence of 0 characters. That's why, in a way, every string at least starts with blank.

If you still want to return `false`, you can do it like so:

```js
var haystack = 'Hello World!',
  needle = '';
console.log(Boolean(needle) && haystack.startsWith(needle));
```

Check for the boolean equivalent of the checker string first, so that if it is blank, the return value becomes `false`.

Comment: You don't need `Boolean`. Empty string is falsy.

Comment: @Tushar -- that's true, but `console.log` prints empty for that expression then.